# redirect after posting javascript variable with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using this code snippet below to post a JavaScript variable to php. It successfully does the operation because in the console log it shows the desired outcome but how to I redirect to the index.php so that I can see it in action. Thanks in advance for all your help and your time.

code snippet

```
var json = jsObj2php(user);
alert(json);
$.post('index.php', {
    json: json
}, function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: What does _see it in action_ mean?

Comment: how about `window.location.href='index.php'` or directly submit form to index.php

Comment: See it in action means I just want to echo out something on the next screen using the object I passed. And I tried window.location.href='index.php' but it doesn't do the job properly because nothing comes on the screen when I try to echo the result. Thanks again for your help and time in advance!

Comment: you should be returning something to that page and using it if your using ajax and putting the value in a div or text box. The index.php won't show you anything unless you supply the get request to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
var json = jsObj2php(user);
alert(json);
$.post('index.php', {
    json: json
}, function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
    window.location.href='index.php?MYDATA=' + data;
});
```

and then in the index.php you could do

```
if(isset($_GET["MYDATA"]) AND !empty($_GET["MYDATA"]))
        echo $_GET["MYDATA"];
```